# Store data from multiple URLs in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, list, csv

I have 10 `URL's` which are `csv` file. I want to store data from multiple URL's in a list in python. All URL's are a csv file in same format.

I have tried:

```
url = request.GET.get('url')         #for first url

data = []
with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as f:
   dfs = [pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in f]
```

I am able to extract the data but how can I get data from rest of the URL's and store all of them in a list.

Comment: You can create a list of 10 urls and then run a for loop for each url in list.

Comment: Just create a list of URLs. Iterate through them in a loop and append the data to a list. Shouldn't be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

if csvs have same number of columns, create list of strings for urls then loop through:

```
url_lst = []
for u in urls:
   i = pd.read_csv(u)
   url_lst.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the combine the contents of the CSV into one file? You could alter your dfs line to be something like:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) for f in all_files])
```

If that is not what you want to do you could convert the data in DFS dataframe to an array with df['col'].values and then convert that to a list() and append the lists to data, so you have a list of lists. If you just want a single list you can flatten the list of list with:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))
```